# Apache Beam Python read .tgz and parse to BigQuery

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have .tgz files , for instance. It resides in Google Cloud Storage. Inside the .tgz is a series of | delimited .txt files.
For instance one of the 10 files could be named similar to

I'd like to use Apache Beam in Python SDK to at minimal read the .tgz and accompanying .txt files, without having to unpack it first. I'd like to parse the | delimited content and send the Collection to BigQuery, in a predefined Dataset.Table.

This is what I have so far.

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam import (coders, io)

raw_logs = (p
            | io.Read("ReadLogsFromGCS", beam.io.TextFileSource(
                      "gs://my-bucket/logs-*.gz",
                      coder=coders.BytesCoder()))
p.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid beam does not support tgz/tar.gz i.e. doubly zipped file at this moment. There is a open [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3867) for the feature. However, it can read a gz file which has one file only inside. sample code below:

```
beam.io.textio.ReadFromText(file_pattern= 'gs://bucket_name/logs-*.gz',compression_type='gzip')
```